# O URL responde apenas com o site aberto

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Eu preciso raspar a informações desta página [aqui](https://www.agmgranite.com/inventory/hill-country-spicewood/?f=reset).

Nas ferramentas do desenvolvedor, encontrei este [link](https://www.agmgranite.com/paginate.php?page=1&lid=3&f=reset&invp=) com as respostas necessárias.

O problema é que o link com as respostas é aberto apenas se o site estiver aberto anteriormente.

Tente abrir o [link](https://www.agmgranite.com/paginate.php?page=1&lid=3&f=reset&invp=) com as respostas em uma aba anônima e verá tudo em branco.

código:

```
import scrapy


class AaidSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'agm'
    starts_urls = [

        'https://www.agmgranite.com/paginate.php?page=1&lid=3&f=reset&invp='
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.body)
```

resposta:

> []

Como raspar essas respostas se precisar do site aberto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

João, Quando você loga no site principal ele te entrega um cookie de navegação.
Para fazer tal requisição você deve passar os parâmetros de header junto a requisição conforme o código abaixo.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.agmgranite.com',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'referer': 'https://www.agmgranite.com/inventory/hill-country-spicewood/?f=reset',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'cookie': 'PHPSESSID=cfd3f3811f8d4bed78f146cd3ed8f3e1; _ga=GA1.2.1369799401.1580910358; _gid=GA1.2.1574686430.1580910358',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.agmgranite.com/paginate.php?page=1&lid=3&f=reset&invp=', headers=headers)
```

Caso obtenha algum problema em capturar o header ou o mesmo venha a expirar depois de algum tempo (Não aconteceu comigo), você pode optar por utilizar o selenium, com ele você pode logar inicialmente no site principal e após isso redirecionar para o link desejado.

Comment: Era o que eu precisava, peguei os cookies via selenium e deu certo! Obrigado :)